# How to write query in springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am making a project where when a user login he will get a mail otp.I have successfully made the login page and also I am sending otp to the user mail address. Now I also want to validate the otp for that I have already created a otp column in database. But I can't figure out how to store the generated otp in the table.
Here is my code.

EmailSenderService class :

```
public class EmailSenderService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    
    public void sendMail(String toEmail,
                         String subject,
                         String body) {
        SimpleMailMessage message=new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom("growthgreek@gamil.com");
        message.setTo(toEmail);
        message.setText(body);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        
        mailSender.send(message);
        System.out.println("message sent .....");   
    }
    
}
```

OtpEmailController Class:

```
@Controller
public class OtpEmailController {
    
    @Autowired
    private EmailSenderService emailService;

    Random random = new Random(1000);
    
    @PostMapping("/send-otp")
    public String sendOtp(@RequestParam("email") String email) {
        
        int otp = random.nextInt(999999);
        
        String subject = "OTP from session-handling-proj By Harshit";
        String toEmail = email;
        String body = "<h1> OTP = " + otp + "</h1>";
        
           this.emailService.sendMail(toEmail, subject, body);
          return ("success");
    }
```

Repository Class :

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface SessionHandlingRepository extends JpaRepository<SessionHandling, Integer>{

    @Query(value="Select * from session_handling where email= :email",nativeQuery =true)
    public SessionHandling findByEmailId(@Param("email")String email);
    
    @Query(value="Select * from session_handling where email= :email AND password= :password",nativeQuery =true)
    public SessionHandling findByEmailIdAndPassword(@Param("email")String email, @Param("password")String password);
}
```

Entity Class :

```
@Entity
public class SessionHandling {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String cpassword;
    
    private static final long OTP_VALID_DURATION = 5 * 60 * 1000;   // 5 minutes
    
    @Column(name = "one_time_password")
    private String oneTimePassword;
     
    @Column(name = "otp_requested_time")
    private Date otpRequestedTime;
```

Where and how to write the query for saving the otp in database?

Comment: YOu don;t nor should you write the other queries. Ditch the `@repostiory`, `@transactional` and all those `@Query` annotations (spring will generate the query etc. foryou). For storing call `save`. You are working around Spring Data instead of working with it. Another thing don't write your own Security solution, use something like Spring Security instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum if I don't write the query, springboot is showing error

Comment: Because your method is named wrongly it should be `findByEmail` and not `findByEmailId` and you then don't need the `@Param` either.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes you were right, after deleting the query it is still running fine. But we require query when we create a custom method right? for eg ``` findByEmailIdAndPassword ```

Comment: No you don't. Only if those don't match properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with your repository, first inject the repository in your service :

```
@Autowired
private SessionHandlingRepository sessionHandlingRepository;
```

you can then create an instance of your entity at the desired location (add getter and setter to the entity first):

```
SessionHandling sessionHandling = new SessionHandling();
sessionHandling.setName("theName");
// call Other setters ...
```

you can use the following repository method to save the entity in the database :

```
sessionHandlingRepository.save(sessionHandling);
```

Comment: I am asking user to give its mail id and then for the specific user i want to set the otp. According to you --- sessionHandling.setName("theName"); --- it will set but how will I mention that set only for the the given mailid ??